# Recursively fetch data from the api

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I need to fetch all the data from the API which is paginated. I have implemented a similar way before when I had a RecyclerView, which onScrolled() I would check if more data is present and then fetch the next page. Now, I do not have any RecyclerView and at first instance, I need to fetch all the data recursively from the API for processing. Should I use RxJava? Not very familiar with RxJava. At the moment I using Retrofit for the API. Any hints on best possible way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you call the API synchronously you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val responses = arrayListOf<Response>()

fun fetchDataFromApi(key: String?) {
    val response = getData(key)
    responses.add(response)
    if(response.hasNext) {
      fetchDataFromApi(response.nextKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not tell total pages, but hasNext as a boolean which would tell if there is a next page. So instead of the iterator<= lastPage, I would just need to check the boolean flag :)